# Using Schur's test

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K\in L^1 (\mathbb{R}^2)\cap L^2 (\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $$Tf(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}K(x-y)f(y)dy$$
Using Schur's test shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_test) prove that $$\|T\|_{L^2}\le\|K\|_{L^1}$$ and in fact that $$\|T\|_{L^2}=\|\hat{K}\|_{L^\infty}$$

Let $\alpha=\beta=\|K\|_1$ and $p(x)=q(y)=1$. Then, we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|K(x,y)|q(y)dy = \|K\|_1$$ and $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}p(x)|K(x,y)|dx = \|K\|_1$$
Then, we have $\|T\|\leq \|K\|_1$ by Schur's test.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Your bounty sits on a  a fairly imprecise post:
**(1)** $K$ is a function on $\mathbb R^2$ but the defining $T$ involves integration over $\mathbb R^n$, and is of type involution ?!
**(2)** Many different norms with different subscripts show up.
**(3)** Meaning of $\hat K$ is not explained.
**(4)** the last two integrals are partial, thus results should still depend on one variable.
**(5)** There is no question at all!
**(5a)** Where are your difficulties?
A careful edit would be welcome!

Comment: * ad (1):  Read "... of type 'Convolution' ".

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Show that $\|T\|\leq \sqrt{\alpha \beta}= \sqrt{\|K\|_1^2}=\|K\|_1$. It's helpful that since you are integrating over $\mathbb{R}^n$, the $L^1$ norms are equal for each fixed $x$ and each fixed $y$.

Comment: But in order to use the Schur's test, you need $\alpha$ and $\beta$ defined, as well as the $p$ and $q$. How would you do that?

Comment: From my hint, it should be obvious what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are. For $p$ and $q$, try picking really easy cases first.

Comment: Can you give me a little more guidance on finding $p$ and $q$ please? I think if I use $p=q=1$, the equality in the condition would work?

Comment: It seems like you are on the right track. If you edit your post with what you have, I can maybe give feedback.

Comment: Edited with progress.